# Opencart Migrating issue

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have migrated my opencart website to the path http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/ , but it shows a blank page when I access the link. I already contacted 123-reg support team but they are saying that coding issues are outside of support scope. I configured 2 php files (config.php , admin/config.php) and rechecked it all seems correct. 
What do I have to change ?

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/smilzo-beta/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/smilzo-beta/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/smilzo-beta/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/storage/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

And admin/config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/smilzo-beta/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/smilzo-beta/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/smilzo-beta/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/storage/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/shootandedit.site/public_html/smilzo-beta/catalog/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');

// OpenCart API
 define('OPENCART_SERVER', 'https://www.opencart.com/');
```

And the old link is working good

```
http://wercreative.in/smilzo-beta/
```

Comment: have you uploaded all the files ?

Comment: Yeah, uploaded all the files and database too

Comment: Please remove your database credentials from your code as they are not needed and provide a security risk

Answer (score 0):

Try This Codes.
[Edit 1] Also, I have removed the .site from the links except for the server ones. 
[Edit 2] Altered the storage links in both the files

Config.php

```
 <?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/storage/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Admin/config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://shootandedit.site/smilzo-beta/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/storage/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/shootandedit/public_html/smilzo-beta/catalog/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');

// OpenCart API
 define('OPENCART_SERVER', 'https://www.opencart.com/');
```

Comment: Why should I 'try' this code? Instead of giving a vague incentive for me to try something which might or might not hack my computer, *explain* why I should 'try' this. Thus please add text and or comments inside the code explaining why this code solves the problem of the OP. This helps future readers to understand why they can use this.

Comment: I have removed the .site from the links except for the server links.

Comment: Hi can you tell me what is the path in the cpanel  also do the change the db_hostname to localhost and try.. Because for the website which i created the hostname is always says localhost rather than the ip.